# DataGridView flickers ONLY when the rows fits roughly one page

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a grid view that is as basic as it can gets. It displays a one-off search result, and does not updates its datasource unless the search button is click again, so I don't think data update is causing the issue.

For example, my search returns 30 rows of results, and my full-screen data grid could fit 40 rows without scrolling, there are no flickering. Then I started to slowly reduce the height of the window. Once the grid view height is slightly less than my 30 rows' height it starts to flicker. But if I further decrease the height of the window so that the grid view could only shows 20 rows, a scrollbar shows up as expected and everything is fine again. Even scrolling up or down doesn't flicker at all.

Although I don't think it is performance related, I've tried things like suspend layout and double buffering which doesn't help as expected.

I think it is something related to auto row height calculation when it is near its boundary condition, but I have no idea how to solve it. Below are the auto row size settings that might/might not affect it.

```
dgv.DataSource = datatable;
dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns["Creation Date"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
dgv.Columns["Creation Date"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
dgv.Columns["Name"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
dgv.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgv.Columns["Name"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgv.Columns["Receipt No."].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
dgv.Columns["Receipt No."].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgv.Columns["Receipt No."].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgv.Columns["Remark"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgv.Columns["Remark"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

This is my double buffering class just in case I messed up

```
public static class BufferedGridView
{
    public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
    {
        Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
    }
}
```

This is where I used it, in the Form that contains the grid view;

```
public ManagementPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dgv.DoubleBuffered(true);
    .......
}
```

Comment: The first thing to check is code in various events which are invalidating or similar which then results in that event getting called again.  A for loop to tinker with all rows is an example

Comment: i double checked that every event are attached to a button (search button to update grid view etc) and there are no custom event being triggered anywhere. There seems to be no loop anywhere except when I need to export the searched data as a PDF, which is also attached to a button. The only event that is being triggered while scrolling or resizing are the default events from datagridview.

Comment: How exactly did you do the double buffering? I strongly believe that it must help.

Comment: updated with buffer code. I don't know enough to say for sure, but isn't buffering is for helping with flickering due to long processing time (e.g. large amount of data or heavy data computation)? In my case this happens even with 20 records with only a few column, displaying raw string data directly from data table without processing.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment below, I've set out the answer again below.  Sorry, I'm fairly new to this site - just trying to help.

It seems you can break the endless loop that causes the flicker by overriding the OnCellValueChanged and OnRowHeightChanged events:

```
protected override void OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        this.Rows[e.RowIndex].MinimumHeight = 2;
    }
    
    base.OnCellValueChanged(e);
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnRowHeightChanged(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MinimumHeight = e.Row.Height;

    base.OnRowHeightChanged(e);
}
```

This basically locks the minimum row height to the height when the row height is updated, and then releases it when the cell value is changed.

Therefore, when the internal DataGridView code tries to resize the rows, they get locked to a minimum (meaning they won't be reduced in size again, which is what causes the endless loop).  When a user (or code) updates a cell, this constraint is released so that the rows can resize when they need to.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and after some analysis concluded it's a bug in .NET that happens in the edge case of when a DataGridView is roughly the same height as the rows it needs to contain, because of an endless loop of adding a vertical scrollbar, adjusting row heights, then removing the scrollbar etc.

I've posted the solution I came up with here: [DataGridView - apparent bug in .NET causing continuous jitter on the grid view when number of rows is roughly the same as the size of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263851/datagridview-apparent-bug-causing-continuous-jitter-on-the-grid-view-when-numb/62267331#62267331)

Comment: instead of new QA post you could have written a detailed answer here