# DataGridView - apparent bug in .NET causing continuous jitter on the grid view when number of rows is roughly the same as the size of the view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the same problem as described here:

[DataGridView flickers ONLY when the rows fits roughly one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735773/datagridview-flickers-only-when-the-rows-fits-roughly-one-page)

Basically, where the number of rows in a DataGridView is roughly the same as the size of the view itself, the DataGridView appears to get caught in an endless loop of resizing the rows/columns.

From running performance profiling on the DataGridView, it appears the onColumnWidthChanged and onRowHeightChanged events are continually firing.  My hunch is that the vertical scrollbar is causing the issue in that:

(1)  when the scroll bar isn't showing, the DataGridView works out row heights, but that for some reason pushes the final row off the screen

(2)  that prompts the scroll bar to show, which prompts a row height/column width recalculation, but for some reason the rows then fit  (I'm not quite sure why this would be - if the scroll bar is there, you'd expect there to be less space)

(3)  that prompts the scroll bar to be removed .... go back to bullet (1)

This endless loop significantly impairs the UI thread, and is visually unsightly.

I've been trying to find a way of detecting and overriding the behaviour (e.g. by trying to detect when the final row is showing, and then force disabling the vertical scrollbar), without any luck so far.

Has anyone come across this please and/or have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From some further investigation, points (1)-(3) is exactly what's happening.  If I slow down execution, you can see the scrollbar being added, the rows resized, the scrollabr disappearing and so on.  The execution is entirely within the event loop and the .NET DataGridView code - nothing within my code.  It seems almost certainly a bug in .NET. The question is how to get around it from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can break the endless loop by overriding the OnCellValueChanged and OnRowHeightChanged events:

```
protected override void OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        this.Rows[e.RowIndex].MinimumHeight = 2;
    }

    base.OnCellValueChanged(e);
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnRowHeightChanged(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MinimumHeight = e.Row.Height;

    base.OnRowHeightChanged(e);
}
```

This basically locks the minimum row height to the height when the row height is updated, and then releases it when the cell value is changed.

Therefore, when the internal DataGridView code tries to resize the rows, they get locked to a minimum (meaning they won't be reduced in size again, which is what causes the endless loop).  When a user (or code) updates a cell, this constraint is released so that the rows can resize when they need to.